# the connection string property has not been initialized. vb.net access. BELOW is the code

Tags: vb.net

```
Try
    If MsgBox("SAVE THIS ACADEMIC YEAR?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, title) = vbYes Then
        cn.Open()
        cm = New OleDbCommand("update [tblay] set status = 'CLOSE'", cn)
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

        cn.Open()
        cm = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [tblay] (aycode,year1,year2,division)values(@aycode,@year1,@year2,@division)", cn)
        With cm
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("aycode", txtAY.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("year1", txtYear1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("year2", txtYear2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("division", cboDivision.Text)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox("NEW ACADEMIC YEAR HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY SAVED!", vbInformation, title)
        With frmAY
            .LoadRecords()
        End With
        Clear()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    cn.Close()
    MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical, title)
End Try
```

**This is the code to load records**:

```
Sub LoadRecords()
    Try
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer
        cn.Open()
        cm = New OleDbCommand("select * from tblay", cn)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            i += 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr.Item("aycode").ToString, dr.Item("year1").ToString, dr.Item("year2").ToString, dr.Item("division").ToString, dr.Item("status").ToString)
        End While
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical, title)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be real nice if you could edit your question and tidy up the formatting some to make it much easier to read.  That aside, you've given us two methods either of which might cause this error, in which and where exactly?  I question why exactly you're closing and immediately re-opening this connection again, that's not needed and may be part of the problem.  I would also look at the Using clause for you Connection handling in general.  Frequently these sorts of problems caused by having public/wide scope connection objects

Comment: Where are you initializing `OleDbConnection`? It should be initialized and disposed of in the method. Also, `OleDbCommand` doesn't use named parameters, although providing a name where the parameters are added can be useful for debugging. In the SQL statement you may consider using `?` as a reminder that named parameters aren't supported.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks, man. Sorry, just a newbie here on stack overflow. but I will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you want so if so sorry.
SQLite Database (DB) CRUD function are very Boiler Plate Code. That Said I use the same process repetably.
By pacing the code in Using blocks NO need to close the DB and other functions.
I create a button for each function SAVE DELETE and UPDATE that call the function.
Here are the functions.

This code needs to be placed top level

```
Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Public conn As SQLiteConnection
```

Here is the SAVE data NOTE the `'{gv_dbName}` is declared in a Module.

```
    Private Sub InsertSiteData()

    dateToday = CDate(CDate(Date.Today).ToString("M-d-yyyy"))

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand
            cmd.Connection = conn
            Try
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LinkTable (ytChannelName,ytLinkAddress,ytLastVisit,ytSiteType) VALUES (@ytChannelName,@ytLinkAddress,@ytLastVisit,@ytSiteType)"

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytChannelName", DbType.String).Value = tbSiteName.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytLinkAddress", DbType.String).Value = tbUrl.Text.Trim
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytLastVisit", DbType.String).Value = dateToday.ToString("M-d-yyyy")
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytSiteType", DbType.String).Value = strType.Trim
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Insert Failed")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    gvTxType = ""
    frmStart.Show()
    Close()

End Sub
```

Here is the DELETE.

```
    Private Sub DeleteSiteData()

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand

            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM LinkTable WHERE LID =" & gvID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
    End Using

    gvTxType = ""
    frmStart.Show()
    Close()

End Sub
```

And the UPDATE.

```
    Public Sub UpdateSiteData()

    dateToday = CDate(CDate(Date.Today).ToString("M-d-yyyy"))

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;"),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand("UPDATE LinkTable SET ytChannelName = @ytChannelName, ytLinkAddress = @ytLinkAddress ,ytLastVisit = @ytLastVisit,ytSiteType = @ytSiteType WHERE LID =" & gvID, conn)
        conn.Open()

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytChannelName", DbType.String).Value = tbSiteName.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytLinkAddress", DbType.String).Value = tbUrl.Text.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytLastVisit", DbType.String).Value = dateToday.ToString("M-d-yyyy")
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytSiteType", DbType.String).Value = strType.Trim
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LID", DbType.String).Value = gvID

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    gvTxType = ""
    frmStart.Show()
    Close()

End Sub
```